# Clash Royale transferring issues

Tags: clash-royale

So, I have my first clash royale account (the original account I want to transfer) on my iphone 5c, then I got an iphone 6s and started a new profile on there and when I try to transfer my iphone 5's data to my iphone 6 it tries to link my iphone 6's account to the iphone 5 and not the iphone 5 to the iphone 6 PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure for your iPhone 5c you selected "THIS IS THE OLD DEVICE" and your iPhone 6s "THIS IS THE NEW DEVICE", everything should flow from there in game.